# Retrieve Data by passing a parameter to url in Android

Tags: java, android, json, httprequest, httpresponse

What I need is to append a parameter to a url to retrieve data & I am using json parser. Getting a perfect result where I don't have to pass a parameter. But not being able to figure out how to pass parameter like String ID to url to retrieve data.

```
     //Inside JSON Response calling class

  JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            JSONArray jArraySearchJob = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url_Jobsearch);

            try{

                for (int i = 0; i < jArraySearchJob.length(); i++) 
                {
            JSONObject jsonElements = jArraySearchJob.getJSONObject(i);

            String J_p_id    = jsonElements.getString(android_J_P_ID);

        HashMap<String, String> hashAmbJobSearch = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key

                    hashAmbJobSearch.put(android_J_P_ID, J_p_id);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList

                    ResultList_JobSearch.add(hashAmbJobSearch);
                }
```

Json Parser:

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;

    static JSONArray jarray = null;

    static String json = "";

    //Method Returns JSON

    public JSONArray getJSONFromUrl(String url) {               

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
         try {
              HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost);

              StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();

              int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

              if (statusCode == 200) 
              {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                InputStream content = entity.getContent();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));

                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
                {
                  builder.append(line);
                }
              } 
              else
              {
                  Log.e("==>", "Failed to download file");
              }
            } 

         catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

         catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try 
        {
            jarray = new JSONArray(builder.toString());
        } 

        catch (JSONException e) 
            {
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }

        // return JSON String
        return jarray;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain more clearly? You need to find a way to pass a parameter in the URL ?

Comment: Exactly.. Simply iwant to pass an string ID to url on the basis of which data is fetched.. like Id = 1 goes for Name = ABC

Comment: @sush Thankx for ur help I would love to upvote your answer but i dont have enough repu to upvote your edit.. Thankx for your help

Comment: atleast accept and as soon u get that sufficient status please upvote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

usually username and password is sent as parameters

```
http://www.sample.url?Username=userNameValue&Password=passwordvalue
```

In case of android.

```
1.For get method as query params
```

`String url = http://www.sample.url?username=+ Uri.encode(UserName) + "&password=" + Uri.encode(password)`

`HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);`

```
2. For post mehod as postparam in querystring (query params is again same as get method only)

3. If you want send as postparams use below code 


        ArrayList<NameValuePair> projectLoginInfo = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        projectLoginInfo.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", userNameValue));
        projectLoginInfo.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", passwordValue));
         HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.sample.url");

         try{      //encode login data and Hands the entity to the request.
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(projectLoginInfo));
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("UnsupportedEncoding", "unable to encode some characters", e1);

            return -1;
        }`
```

you should use below code in your Json Parser class

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> projectLoginInfo = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    projectLoginInfo.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", userNameValue));
    projectLoginInfo.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", passwordValue));
     HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.sample.url");

     try{      //encode login data and Hands the entity to the request.
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(projectLoginInfo));
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1)
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("UnsupportedEncoding", "unable to encode some characters", e1);

        return null;
    }`
          HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost);
          StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
```

Comment: plz do clear me.. i have to use this code in Json Parser class or while calling Json Response ?

Comment: You build the query first and then call the URL. The above code has to be called first and then call the getJSONFromURL method and pass in that url as parameter